# Formulae for SharePoint List not working

Tags: excel, sharepoint

=IF([End Date]=''" , "TBC",IF[End Date]< (Today -14), "Archived" , IF([End Date]

This formulae for a calculated field in a SharePoint list is not working. End date is a column and Today I think it the function for todays date in sharepoint.

Error is syntax is wrong ?

Comment: , IF[End Date]<Today,"Inactive", "Active" bracket bracket . End of formulae

Comment: Are you doing this in Excel or SharePoint? Why the Excel tag?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're doing this in a SharePoint calculated column and not Excel ( its not clear from your question and tags) then Steve is correct about the syntax but there is a bigger problem.

[You can't use Today in SharePoint calculated column formula - it does not work.](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/)

You will find plenty of articles talking about the fake Today column trick but it doesn't work as the result of the formula only updates when you update the record. Look again tomorrow and you will still see todays result - it won't have updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra quote in your first IF.

Instead of this:

```
=IF([End Date]=''" , "TBC",IF([End Date]< (Today -14), "Archived" , IF([End Date]<Today,"Inactive", "Active" ))
```

Try this:

```
=IF([End Date]="" , "TBC",IF([End Date]< (Today -14), "Archived" , IF([End Date]<Today,"Inactive", "Active" ))
```

Comment: If only Excel had syntax highlighting the way it is here!